# Problems in updating from PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form that I want to have record changes update my SQL database-table.

In my index.php-file I have f.ex this:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
$tbname = "myVis";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tbname . " WHERE id = '$_POST[id]'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $firstname = $row['firstname'];
      $lastname = $row['lastname'];
      $image = $row['image'];
      $course = $row['course'];
      $frdate = $row['frdate'];
      $todate = $row['todate'];
      $email = $row['email'];
      $checkout = $row['checkout'];
    }
  }
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
...
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action='' method='post'>
    <table>
...
        <tr>
          <td>Efternamn:</td>
           <td>
            <input id="lastname2" type="text" value='<?php echo  $lastname; ?>' /></td>
        </tr>
...
      </table>

      <?php
           if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
...
            if (isset($_POST['lastname2'])) {
              $lastname  = $_POST['lastname2'];
            }
...
            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "password";
            $dbname = "myDB";
            $tbname = "myVis";
            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
              die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            $sql2 = "UPDATE " . $tbname . " SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', image='$image', course='$course', frdate='$frdate', todate='$todate', email='$email', checkout='$checkout' WHERE id ='".$_POST['id']."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            if ($result) {
               echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
               echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
          }
        }
      ?>

      <input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Spara" />
      <input type="button" name="back" id="back" value="Tillbaka" onclick="history.back()" />

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to change a value (say lastname) nothing changes and all values are back to the selected record from the db-table.
How can I get PHP to understand and have a changed value update the table?
Don't quite understand the sequence in my index-file.

Please help.
Regards,
/Fredrik.

Comment: Your html doesn't look valid And why do you prefer to create a new database connection everytime?

Comment: Such questions are off topic here. We don't do a code review here. Especially if most of the code is stripped from example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your submit code at the top of the page after your database connection. Then when you submit the form first match the table column with submitted post values. If any column has different post value then update that column.

Comment: I come to this page from another page where I post a submit for the id, that's why I select on top.